# what is "root:'data' " extjs store config

Tags: javascript, extjs, proxy, treeview

I am very new to ExtJs and I have the following code for a treeView,,which has a default root in the beginning and then an Ajax call to a servlet .But i don't understand the 'root' field with value 'data' .Is data an alias or xType .Here is the code:

```
   Ext.define('Eits.view.OrgTreeView', {
extend : 'Ext.tree.TreePanel',
requires: ['Eits.model.OrgTreeModel'],
    width : '100%',
    region : 'center',
    border : true,

    store : {
        xtype : 'tree',
        fields : Eits.model.OrgTreeModel.FIELDS,
        //model: 'Eits.model.OrgTreeModel',
        autoLoad: false,
        root: {
            id: 'rootNode',
            objectId : 'rootNode',
            leaf: false,
            expanded: false,
            text : 'MTS',
            iconCls : 'mts-Tree-Node',
        },
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'orgTree/getNavigationTree.action',
            actionMethods: 'POST',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'data'     
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`root`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader-cfg-root) property is:

> The name of the property which contains the data items corresponding
>   to the Model(s) for which this Reader is configured. For JSON reader
>   it's a property name (or a dot-separated list of property names if the
>   root is nested). For XML reader it's a CSS selector. For Array reader
>   the root is not applicable since the data is assumed to be a
>   single-level array of arrays.
>
> By default the natural root of the data will be used: the root JSON
>   array, the root XML element, or the array.
>
> The data packet value for this property should be an empty array to
>   clear the data or show no data.

(Extjs's documentation is a great resource when using the framework)